# Is OpenPGP encryption a valid replacement for SSL when passing messages?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, pgp

I am writing an application that occasionally needs to transmit larger messages to other servers on the internet without allowing people to snoop on the traffic. The normal way to handle this is to get an SSL certificate and use an encrypted connection for the communication channel.

However, trusted certs cost money and I don't want to require my users purchase one to transmit data.

Currently, I'm trying to decide if using self-signed certificates or PGP would be a better idea. If I use PGP I can just have the servers pass each others public key back and forth before they send the data.

What is the proper way to use free encryption for something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you use PGP if you can just sign the certificates with your own generated root certificate and just add the public root certificate  to all your participating servers/clients?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to be able change certificates if needed. I also don't control these other nodes so I need to be able to pass my cert or public key when they are needed. This isn't really about nodes trusting each other, just having a private conversation.

Comment: So how do you plan to safely exchange your public key (so the other node knows for sure it's in  fact your public key)? The problem is the same for SSL as openPGP...

Comment: Assuming node A wants to send data to node B, node A calls B and asks for it's public key (and caches it). Then node A calls back node B and gives the data to node B. node B then calls up node A and asks for it's public key so it can decode the data that A gave it (and caches it for a bit). Let me know if this wrong. :)

Comment: Hey, I'm node A (trust me!). My public key is 0xF00. ;)

Comment: See that's where you have a problem (like Henning Klevjer illustrates) you can't verify node A his identity

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem I guess. No one can claim to be node A unless they change their IP to A's IP and then get the routers to direct my traffic to them instead of the real node A's IP.

Comment: "Hello I'm node C, today I will put myself between node A and B and take on node A his IP. I will keep passing messages to node B, but not before reading all the messages. I will tell node A I'm B and I'll tell node B I'm A." There is no way you will be able to tell if someone is doing a MITM if you do not have a certain web of trust (safe distribution of public keys)

Comment: If I were you I'd buy this book and read it: http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networking-Top-Down-Approach-Edition/dp/0136079679 It has all these kind of problems explained :)

Comment: Thanks, I see that book has a more recent version too. Also, it makes sense that I could get around the MITM attack by doing like you said and generating a root cert, and then distribute it with the application to all the servers.